# Order of execution: One Property in Two Bindings?

Tags: javafx, binding

When I have a Property as a Dependency in two different Bindings; and the Property isChanged - what binding will be called/recalculated first?

I did a practice:

```
        y.bind(a.or(b));

        x.bind(a.or(c));

        x.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("x has changed");
        });

        y.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("y has changed");    
        });
```

when I change **a**, the first binding, where **a** was added as a dependency is called (y). so, does only the order of the addition matter or is there anything else to know? the call order is: y-listener, x-listener

Edit:

When I do add a listener for **a** like:

```
  a.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean          oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("a has changed");
        });

        y.bind(a.or(b));

        x.bind(a.or(c));

        x.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("x has changed");
        });

        y.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("y has changed");    
        });
```

However I added an additional Listener to **a** bevor the bindings were made, still the call order is like that, but why?:
y-listener, x-listener, a-listener.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's because of the order of the declaration of the bindings: `y.bind(a.or(b)); x.bind(a.or(c));`. The workflow is something like: `a` is marked to be changed -> all the bindings going to be invalidated: at first `y` - `y` fires the change event which is in the queue; then `x` is changed - the change event of `x` is also in the queue now -> finally `a` also puts its event to the queue: y -> x -> a.

Comment: thank you - but what I don't understand is, when I change a, why the a-Listener is not called first?is there (any other) way to being notified about change of value a first?